# How to align first gallery item to the left?

Tags: android, android-gallery

By default, gallery is center aligned. The behavior I want, is to left align the first item in the parent layout instead of centering it. How it can be done?
I have also gone through the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341158/android-align-first-item-in-gallery-to-the-left

But that doesn't work for 2.3.x devices.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Answer suggested in the added link not working on HTC 2.3.3 device as well as in Kindle Fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer in the link provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341158/android-align-first-item-in-gallery-to-the-left working perfectly fine. The problem is that I had **wrapped Gallery in FrameLayout** and hence it is not working when I changed it to RelativeLayout, it is working fine.

Comment: dead link 404 error

Answer (score 2):

private void alignGalleryToLeft(Gallery gallery) {

```
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    int galleryWidth = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    // We are taking the item widths and spacing from a dimension resource
    // because:
    // 1. No way to get spacing at runtime (no accessor in the Gallery
    // class)
    // 2. There might not yet be any item view created when we are calling
    // this
    // function
    int itemWidth = getsize(105);
    int spacing = getsize(10);

    // The offset is how much we will pull the gallery to the left in order
    // to simulate left alignment of the first item
    final int offset;
    if (galleryWidth <= itemWidth) {
        offset = galleryWidth / 2 - itemWidth / 2 - spacing;
    } else {
        offset = galleryWidth - itemWidth - 2 * spacing;
    }

    // Now update the layout parameters of the gallery in order to set the
    // left margin
    MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) gallery.getLayoutParams();
    mlp.setMargins(-offset, mlp.topMargin, mlp.rightMargin,
            mlp.bottomMargin);
}
```

getsize() is a method:

```
public int getsize(int sizeInDip) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) ((sizeInDip * metrics.density) + 0.5);
}
```

pass your value in DPI into this method.

Hope,it will work for you.